# How to pass parameters from Wordpress Contact Form 7 to an external server?

Tags: wordpress, forms, parameters, server, contacts

I have a login form created in Wordpress using Contact form 7. I'm tryig to pass parameters from this form to an external server. But it is not happening.

I am a designer, and not much of a programmer. I understand code(sometimes) but can not write it from the scratch. 
I have designed a website for a client. This client has a "Flying Returns" like logistic membership system in which members get lots of perks in shipping etc. This system is on their own server. They want the users to log in to that system from this website.

So I have created a login form using Contact Form 7. I have set *skip_mail: on;* I have tried a few plugins login, but either they dont log into different servers or are expensive, or does not yield correct URL and hence does not log into the system. Therefore I have finally decided to make it happen using code.

Their programmer has given me following JS code that will take the parameters from this form and pass on to their system. IF the parameters are correct, then the user is logged into the system and taken to the member's dashboard page on their server (not my website/server), else it returns an error message, *{"error":"Login Data Incorrect.."}*
I have tried to put this code with  in the contact form. Here is the code (i've hidden the actual IP address, sorry):

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
alert( "Fire!" );
document.location.href="http://49.XXX.XXX.202:XXXX/glslink/servlet/GPLogin?password="+$('#password').val()+"&emailid="+$('#emailid').val();
}, false );
</script>
```

If I remove the *document.location* line, it shows the alert. But the above, in its entirety does nothing. If I use the URL, replace variables with actual values and paste it browser, it logs me into the system without a hitch. 
I have tried quite a few different codes which I could find as possible solution on internet, this site including, but to no avail.

Please help me out. I want the email and password to be passed to this external server, if they are correct then the user should log in and see their dashboard there. Else if it gives the above mentioned error message, then I should be able to reset the form and give an error message to the user.

Comment: Did you try this plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-to-api/

Comment: Hey @Jasie, 

Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it now, but it too does not work. I checked the log it comes with and it gives following error:

    [0] => cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 49.248.28.202 port 8095: Connection refused

Comment: Good. Well, if the server is not reachable, your JS code cannot pass contact form 7's parameters there... Can you reach this server otherwise?

Comment: Update: I managed to get it working, but I had to install their second plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/
However, if the login credentials are incorrect, and it returns the jason {"error":"Login Data Incorrect.."} , could you please tell me how to I show the error message on my login screen?

Comment: Congrats! But Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. You gotta try for yourself, first. If you fail, write a new issue.

Comment: I appreciate that. And I know its not a free coding service, so I really hesitated to come to it for solution for almost 7 days. I tried all possible solutions I could find, even asked two of my programmer friends for help, who couldnt find the solutions themselves because they do not know how wordpress work, & then I came to StackOverflow.
And in the part where I have to clearly mention what I expect as resolution of my query, I did mention these two things, sending parameters and using error message. 
I'd accept any plugin as you suggested, or a redirect as solution as long as it works.

Comment: I think in your case using Contact Form 7 is a bad option. You would better off with a custom form and corresponding custom action to capture the form data, post it to the external api. That would be less troublesome than integrating multiple plugins.

Comment: Do you mean HTML form?